# Play 2 - External configuration file fails to load in production mode

Tags: configuration, playframework-2.0

I am having trouble including an external file in the `application.conf` of my play 2.1.1 application in production mode (when launched with `start`)

Following the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Configuration) I added an `include` statement in my `application.conf` :

```
[...]
include "/absolute/path/to/external/config/file.conf"
```

The content is loaded this way :

```
configuration.getConfig("some-key")
```

It works fine in dev mode, but fails in production mode (it's always `None`).

This is preventing me from deploying my application to production.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Following Saffron's comment I tried a few workarounds.

Removing the first slash from the include statement did not work.

Loading the configuration file via -Dconfig.file=/abs/path gave weird results and it seems that Play is not behaving in a consistent way:

`play start -Dconfig.file=/path/to/file.conf` does not work. However launching `play` THEN running `start -Dconfig.file=/path/to/file.conf` does work ??!!

So I ended up creating a new configuration instead of using Play's:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("/path/to/file.conf")).resolve()
val myValues =  new Configuration(conf).getConfig("some-key").get
```

Hope it can help someone who ran into the same issue.

Comment: I am using Play 2.2 with Scala. I am also facing same issue here. I tried using `-Dconfig.file` as described in Play documentation [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration), but it doesn't work. I still get configuration error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem in which my images weren't displayed correctly in prod mode, but were ok in dev mode.
The solution was to write the path as ("images/...") instead of ("/images/..."). Try it, just for science sake.

Anyway,if this doesn't work, here is some documentation about additional Conf in prod mode, with console lines to override the file. `$ start -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf`

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Unfortunately both workarounds you suggested do not solve the problem. I ended up creating a a new configuration (see my edit).